# What does the VertexMoving method for FindGraphCommunities do?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, cluster-analysis

I've been applying the `VertexMoving` method to some graph data, and it's producing very useful results. However, I've got no clue as to what this method actually *is*, and the documentation is spectacularly vague. Does anyone know what this method does?

Comment: My guess it's some version of "divide vertices into two groups, then move one vertex that has maximal increase / smallest decrease in modularity, repeat until all vertices moved only once, find maximal modularity intermediate state, repeat whole process on that until no further increase in modularity..." kind of thing found in literature. Most based on 70's work of  Kernighan & Lin (yes, *that* Kernighan )

Comment: What is this method? `FindGraphCommunities[g,Method->"VertexMoving"]` doesn't do anything....

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58136/12

Answer (score 3):

Update: I got excellent answers from people elsewhere, so I'll post them here for anyone who finds this question in the future. It turns out that the algorithm is described in these papers:

http://www.atlantis-press.com/php/pub.php?publication=ccit-14&frame=http%3A//www.atlantis-press.com/php/paper-details.php%3Fid%3D11031

http://www.cc.gatech.edu/dimacs10/papers/%5B17%5D-gsw-xxx-11.pdf